# Integer Partitions asymptotic behaviour

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Let $ P(n) $ be the number of partitions of number $n$.

Prove that $ P(n)$, grows faster than any polynomial from $n$.

I am looking for an elementary (rather bijective) proof of the fact.

Comment: This comes from the generating function for $P(n,k)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on that?

Comment: @guser: do you know the asymptotic behaviour of $[x^m]\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$, for instance? The pole of order $k+1$ at $x=1$ gives that such coefficients grow like $m^k$. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) , too.

Comment: I don't know about the asymptotic behavior of those coefficients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of *ordered* partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts is, by the usual combinatorial "stars and bars" argument, $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$: imagine placing $n$ objects in a row and adding $k-1$ dividers in the $n-1$ spaces between them.

As a result, a lower bound for the number of *unordered* partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts is $\frac1{k!} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, which is $\Omega(n^{k-1})$. This is also, of course, a lower bound for $P(n)$.

The argument works for any $k$, proving that $P(n)$ grows faster than a polynomial of any degree.

Answer (score 1):

If $P(n,k)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $k$ parts, then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n,k)t^n=\frac1{(1-t)(1-t^2)\cdots(1-t^k)}.$$
(If $P(n,k)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into at **exactly** $k$ parts, then the generating function is $t^k$ times this.)

This has a partial fraction expansion as a linear combination of
terms of the form $1/(1-\zeta t)^m$ where $\zeta$ is a root of unity
and $m$ is a positive integer. The dominant contribution to the
generating function will come from the term involving $1/(1-t)^k$.

Comment: But still I cannot understand why the coefficients of that generating function should grow faster than $n^k$

Comment: @guser Think about $P(n,1)$. Does this grow faster than $n^1$?

Comment: No it is constant and it is equal to 1. The statement is not true for k=2 as well as $P(n,2)=n$ but for bigger $k$ it is true. There are much stronger results than this one.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas

Comment: @guser So you know what you asked to prove is false for $k=1$ and for $k=2$. Is it true for $k=3$? For **any** $k$?

Comment: Sorry I have corrected the statement

Comment: @guser You have completely changed the question. Anyway $P(n)$ grows as fast as any $P(n,k)$.

Comment: $P(n)$ is a sum over all k $P(n,k)$

Answer (score 1):

Look at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function

An asymptotic formula
for $p(n)$,
the number of partitions of $n$,
is
$p(n)
\approx \dfrac1{4n\sqrt{3}}\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{2n}{3}}\right)
$.

An elementary proof of this
by Erdos is at
Erdős, Pál (1942). "On an elementary proof of some asymptotic formulas in the theory of partitions". Ann. Math. (2). 43: 437–450. Zbl 0061.07905. doi:10.2307/1968802.

This implies
$\ln p(n)
\approx C\sqrt{n}
$
where
$C = \pi\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}
$.
All that is needed for your result
is that
$\ln p(n)
\gt k\ln(n)
$
for any $k > 0$.

In G. H. Hardy's book
"RAMANUJAN
TWELVE LECTURES ON
SUBJECTS SUGGESTED BY HIS LIFE AND WORK",
chapter 8 has
an elementary proof that
$e^{A\sqrt{n}}
\le p(n)
\lt e^{B\sqrt{n}}
$
for some reals
$A$ and $B$.
This is based on
the generating function
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p(n)x^n
=\dfrac1{\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-x^m)}
$.